# nurbs straight line between first two control points

Tags: nurbs

I have been working on a piece of code that takes in a curve (cloud of points with x,y coordinates only for now) and parameterises it to approximate the given shape with nurbs. The issue I have is that the resultant parameterised curve is linear(!) between the first two control points and only between the other ones approximates the input curve. Any idea on why that would happen (i.e. the linear segment between the first two control points)?

Also, the system wouldn't let me post a picture. Hope the problem is clear enough though..

Comment: A nurbs curve is typically curvy unless the first k control points (where k is order of the nurbs curve) are in fact collinear or your nurbs curve is in fact of degree 1. So, it will be nice if you can post a picture of the curve with its control points also shown.

Answer (score 0):

Your software system most probably uses multiple start and end points. This leads to visually straight lines at the given control points. These are in fact not really linear going,  they only look like.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for replying and looking at my problem, but I have found the bug in my code. I used the number of points from the input curve rather than the number of control points wanted (which have similar variable names in my code) to compute the knot vector and thus the problem propagated from that point onwards.